# QT: Connect QMediaPlayer to QProgressBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer, qprogressbar

I want to connect the QProgressBar to the QMediaPlayer for Song Progress in QT5.
How can i do that?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the QProgressBar to QMediaPlayer like this:

```
connect(player, durationChanged(qint64), progressBar, setMaximum(int));
connect(player, positionChanged(qint64), progressBar, setValue(int));
```

You can also create a slot to normalize int64 to int.

See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-musicplayer-example.html